# Find value in an array using minimum number of checks

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting, search

I am trying to solve a tricky algorithm question that has been puzzling me.

Imagine we have a strictly decreasing array of integers and a target value `k`. We want to find the target value `k`. This is simple using a search algorithm, however there is another condition. Imagine that, if you check for the value of any number in the array, you increase your penalty `p` by 1. We want to find the target value, and more importantly, by minimizing the total penalty `p` that we incur.

Our goal is to have at most `p=2` penalty, which could result in a `O(sqrt(n))` running time. I am honestly stumped. Does anyone have any idea on how we could go about this?

Here is an example:

`[200, 150, 120, 115, 110, 100]` Imagine `k` = 110. We want to have only 2 checks (so that `p` = 2), with a running time of `O(sqrt(n))`.

Comment: O(sqrt(6)) is meaningless, as that is equivalent to O(1).

Comment: Sorry, yes you are correct. Overall, we want to find the asymptotic number p, where p is a constant, as a worst case as a function of p. In general, if p = 2, we want O(sqrt(n)). An easier goal could be for p = 3 and O(sqrt(n)).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean here. What is an "asymptotic number p"? And "as a function of p", but then you give a function of n?

Comment: We want to know what the worst case is for the amount of numbers we check. This is just a generic explanation of our actual goal, which is p=2 and O(sqrt(n)) running time.

Comment: Obviously it is impossible to only have two checks in an array of 6 values if you want to find *any* given value. You would need 3 in the worst case, which is ceil(log2(6+1)).

Comment: Possibly you have misunderstood the assignment (there are strange wordings and inconsistent phrases in your question and comments). Including a literal quote of the assignment, possibly with a link could clarify things.

Comment: a better algorithm doesn't exist as of right now, there's nothing more to that. You were given an impossible assignment

Comment: Note that O(sqrt(n)) is worse than O(log(n)). For example if n=64, sqrt(n)=8 but log2(n)=6. A binary search gives you O(log(n)) complexity, which is the best you can get.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mahrkeenerh said, the widely-accepted "best way" to search in sorted arrays is binary search (in this case fitted to work with reversed arrays). This method, does result in `p = 3, given by ceil(log2(6+1))` since the array you gave has 6 elements, but it is the fastest method, especially when the size of the array to search within grows.

Here is a binary search fitted so that it works with backwards arrays.

Given in JavaScript so that it may work as a snippet inside your browser. You may translate it to Python.

```js
let p = 0;
const BinarySearch = (arr, x , start=0, end=arr.length) => {
    p++;
    if(end < start) return -1;
    let mid = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);
    if(arr[mid] === x) return mid;
    if(arr[mid] > x) return BinarySearch(arr, x, mid+1, end);
    else return BinarySearch(arr, x , start, mid-1);
};


const MyArray = [200, 150, 120, 115, 110, 100];
console.log("Found at:", BinarySearch(MyArray, 110), 
  "Penalty:", p);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best possible way you can find a value inside sorted array is: Binary search

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: Unfortunately, regular binary search results in our penalty `p` being too high. This is the crevasse of the problem. For p = 2, we want a O(sqrt(n)) running time.

Comment: there is no better way to do it, I gave you the best solution there is. If you come up with something better (which likely you won't), you are in for a treat, numerous prices and  some rewards.